# Standard imports of Java Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

Java Servlets use usually the following import statements:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

If I get it right then javax.servlet.* imports everything inside the package. And because .http is a subpackage of .servlet:

**Isn't the third statement unnecessary?**

import javax.servlet.* should include .http already.

Or is my assumption wrong. Then please correct me.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the third import statement and compile your code?

Comment: Compile Error got.

Comment: In this case you answered your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Java **don't** do that.

Importing `javax.servlet.*` imports all of the types in the `javax.servlet` package but not the types declared in `javax.servlet.http`.

[See tutorial (Apparent Hierarchies of Packages section)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Comment: Okay. You got to distinguish. javax.servlet.* imports just the classes (the files) with that prefix but NOT the subpackages.

Comment: *prefix* you mean the package containing the types?. Yes. *type* I mentioned refers to `class` & `interface` of that `package`.

Comment: Yep. I meant this main.subpackage string. Thanks a lot.